# mod_rewrite Blocking user agent post requests with empty referral strings

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

My wordpress website is getting inundated with post requests.  It is nearing 200,000 requests a day.

Here is a sample of the apache access log:

```
218.75.48.179 - - [24/Jun/2014:13:16:13 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
195.226.235.101 - - [24/Jun/2014:13:16:13 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
186.116.184.32 - - [24/Jun/2014:13:16:14 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
95.43.217.197 - - [24/Jun/2014:13:16:14 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
110.168.188.207 - - [24/Jun/2014:13:16:14 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
113.161.194.225 - - [24/Jun/2014:13:16:14 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
80.9.11.226 - - [24/Jun/2014:13:16:14 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
```

I'm trying to block these requests with mod_rewrite while still allowing the wordpress mod_rewrite code to work. What I have so far isn't properly blocking the requests. Can someone take a look and give me some suggestions?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 "403 Error"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
RewriteRule ^.* 403 [F,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I currently am denying all traffic other than my ip address.

You shouldn't use `%{HTTP_REFERER}` for this. You need to use `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` for this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=11.22.33.44
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
RewriteRule ^.* 403 [F,L]
```

Change `11.22.33.44` with your actual IP address.

Comment: Sorry. I think my original post might be a bit confusing. I'll remove the sentence "I currently am denying all traffic other than my ip address" as that part of the htaccess file isn't displayed above and is only there until the mod_rewrite section is working properly.

Comment: But you can still use `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` to allow only your computer to do POST. It is much more safer than weak `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` check.

Comment: Ha, I hadn't seen `!=` before. Cool. :)

Comment: Wouldn't this also stop legitimate users from submitting a contact form?

Comment: So far you hadn't told the requirement that you have legit POST forms also. IN any case how do you think `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$` would have helped you since clients can send any non empty REFERER to bypass this.

Comment: After looking at the number of ip addresses being used, I don't think blocking by ip address is a viable solution. I feel like my mod_rewrite rule is close. I just need someone to fine tune it.

Comment: You mean you're close due to this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$`